# How to incorporate an external template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to include a search box provided in this local source: http://dnauck.github.io/angular-advanced-searchbox/

I went through all the steps, but I can't figure out how to properly complete this last step:

The `angular-advanced-searchbox` directive uses an external template stored in `angular-advanced-searchbox.html`. Host it in a place accessible to your page and set the `template-url` attribute. Note that the `url` param can be a scope variable as well as a hard-coded string.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: What part don't you understand or are having problems with?

Comment: The implementation within the code of including the external template.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source file on the github page](https://github.com/dnauck/angular-advanced-searchbox/blob/master/src/angular-advanced-searchbox.js#L26), you can see what he means. You can set the template url by the string `'angular-advanced-searchbox.html'` which is a relative path to the html file in the same folder, or you can set it by the attribute `templateUrl` by referring to `attr.templateUrl`. This would be a string set when you call the directive in your html file as in `<nit-advanced-searchbox template-url="templatUrlString'/>`

Answer (score 0):

It basically mean that you can create your own template (With your own style and structure) instead of the default. How?

- This is the default template the module is using: https://github.com/dnauck/angular-advanced-searchbox/blob/master/src/angular-advanced-searchbox.html

You can use change this template structure (But you should keep the directives that the module need to run) and use it instead of the default template, by wrapping it with `<script type="text/ng-template" id="myNewTemplateName.html"></script>`:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myNewTemplateName.html">
    <!-- PUT HERE YOUR NEW TEMPLATE -->
</script>
```

And then you need to introduce your template to the module:

```
<nit-advanced-searchbox
    ng-model="searchParams"
    parameters="availableSearchParams"
    template-url="myNewTemplateName.html" <!-- NOTE THE TEMPLATE DECLARATION --> 
    placeholder="Search...">
</nit-advanced-searchbox>
```

There are additional ways to include and reuse templates in your app - see [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) documentation to learn more. There is also this [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/templatecache-tutorial) about templates.